# Prove $det(A)=\prod_{\lambda\in Spec(A)} \lambda^{m_\lambda}$ where $m_\lambda$ is the algebraical multiply, and $A\in Mat_3(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove $det(A)=\prod_{\lambda\in Spec(A)} \lambda^{m_\lambda}$ where $m_\lambda$ is the algebraical multiply, and $A\in Mat_3(\mathbb{C})$

I was thinking in use canonical form of jordan, but i cannot use this. (Formally i never seen the theory of this)

Then, for definition $det(A)=\sum \epsilon(\sigma)a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}a_{3\sigma(3)}$

But i don't see how can i prove this by definition. Can someone help me?

Note: $Spec(A)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: What definition of determinant are you using, and what theorems about determinants do you know?

Comment: If you define the algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalues throught the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then you just need to prove that the determinant is the degree zero term

Comment: This result can be derived from the Schur's lemma.

Comment: To begin with, how do you define the algebraic multiplicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Write the eigen expansion, then take $det(M \Lambda M^{-1})$.
Note: $det(M)=1/det(M^{-1})$